# datepicker is traped inside the button menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, react-redux

Hi im new in react and i have been using react-datepicker but i got this problem, i made a custom button that when is clicked it should display the datepicker and well it does it, the problem is that it is trapped inside the menu of the button, and what i need is it to popout outside the menu (actually i need to close the menu when selected and just see the datepicker)

any kind of help would be apreciated

[image: menu showing the button for the datepicker]
[image: inside the red circle is the datepicker]

as you can see my datepicker is inside a menu

this is my menu and datepicker code

```
<Menu

className="main-toolbar__menu"
anchorEl={this.state.anchors.options_settings}
open={Boolean(this.state.anchors.options_settings)}
onClose={() => this.handleDropdownClose('options_settings')}
```

>

```
    <MenuItem
      onClick={() => {
        this.toggleCalendar()     
      }}
    >
    <DatePicker
      customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
      selected={this.state.startDate}
      onChange={this.handleChange} 
    />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem
      onClick={() => {
        this.handleModal('addNotificationModal', true)
        this.handleDropdownClose('options_settings')
      }}
    >
      <span>Notification Preferences</span>
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Move your datepicker outside the Menu component and toggle it based on the toggle logic and a ternary expression.

```
 state = {
showCalendar:false
}
toggleCalendar = () => {
      this.setState({showCalendar:!this.state.showCalendar})
//or whatever logic you have for toggleCalendar already
}

  {this.state.showCalendar ? <DatePicker
          customInput={<ExampleCustomInput />}
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange} 
        /> : null }

       <Menu
    className="main-toolbar__menu"
    anchorEl={this.state.anchors.options_settings}
    open={Boolean(this.state.anchors.options_settings)}
    onClose={() => this.handleDropdownClose('options_settings')}
    >

        <MenuItem
          onClick={() => {
            this.toggleCalendar()     
          }}
        >

        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem
          onClick={() => {
            this.handleModal('addNotificationModal', true)
            this.handleDropdownClose('options_settings')
          }}
        >
          <span>Notification Preferences</span>
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
```

Comment: i tried this, and it looks better, but it stills trapped on the menu